# How long does a deleted gmail account take to be deleted permanently from google servers?

Tags: gmail, delete

How long does google keep information on deleted gmail accounts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 2020 state of conditions

There is no clear answer to your question. It depends on the data itself.

Extracts from the official Google site about Privacy and Terms state that:

> We’ll keep this data in your Google Account until you choose to remove it. And if you use our services without signing in to a Google Account, we also offer you the ability to delete some information linked to what you use to access our services, like a device, browser or app.

Further down it is mentioned:

> We keep some data for the life of your Google Account if it’s useful for helping us understand how users interact with our features and how we can improve our services. For example, after you delete a specific Google search from My Activity, we might keep information about how often you search for things, but not what you searched for. When you delete your Google Account, the information about how often you search for things is also removed.

There is also the part about:

> **Information retained for extended time periods for limited purposes**   Sometimes business and legal requirements oblige us to
> retain certain information, for specific purposes, for an extended
> period of time. For example, when Google processes a payment for you,
> or when you make a payment to Google, we’ll retain this data for
> longer periods of time as required for tax or accounting purposes.
> Reasons we might retain some data for longer periods of time include:
>
> Security, fraud & abuse prevention   Financial record-keeping
> Complying with legal or regulatory requirements   Ensuring the
> continuity of our services   Direct communications with Google

Please read the  [full page](https://policies.google.com/technologies/retention).

Have a further reading of the [Gmail Program Policies](https://www.google.com/gmail/about/policy/)

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.